How to change slide animation to fade when switching to virtual desktop?
I dont want to disable animation, like it's possible in accessibility settings, just replace the slide left to right animation to fade animation.
How to do it ?

Please read the info on this site. After that edit and make this a question with some details that might get an answer. https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask
